# Explanation of my R code

Tags: r

```
y<-c(3,5,6,10,12,1) 
y[y%in%1:5]<-0
```

Can any one explain this? my output is  `0  0  6 10 12  0`

Comment: You assigned the elements in 'y' that have values 1:5 to 0. i.e in the `y` vector there is 3, 5 and 1 that intersects with the values in second vector.  But if you want the first 5 values in 'y' to be 0.  try `y[seq_along(y) %in% 1:5]<- 0` or even `y[1:5] <- 0`

Answer (score 2):

`y[y%in%1:5]<-0` reads like

1. Take the vector `y`
2. Look at a subset of it `[`
3. The subset shall be every value which is `%in%` the value range of `1,2,3,4,5`
4. Assign (`<-`) `0` to the subset

Comment: I find it easier to read from inside out. So in `y` find values of `1:5`. If found, extract it from `y` using `[` and overwrite with `0`.